# How to load a jquery once only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna have a banner in the header of my site that appears the first a user enters the site.
The html structure looks like this:

```
   <div class="mobilebanner">
        <div class="mobilebanner-container">
            <div class="left-box">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?> /images/sample.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h4>The New Yorker Today</h4>
                    <p>Conde Nast Digital</p>
                    <div class="review-stars">
                        <p>starts willlbe here</p>
                    </div>
                    <p>GET - On the App Store</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-box">
                <div class="view">
                    <a href="www.gmail.com">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click on the image, the banner must disappear and only show again if the user visits the site after 24 hours.

Hope someone can help me achieve that from [my pen here](https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/mWMYGP)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need localStorage/cookies, not jQuery

Comment: @Mehul Mohan. Don't really know to do that. can you help?

Comment: wher is your JS ?

Comment: Here is my pen https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/mWMYGP

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete code. But it'll get you to what you want to do.

```
window.onload = function() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('timestamp')) {
     var timestampDate = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('timestamp'));
     if(timestampDate + 24*60*60*1000 < new Date().getTime()) { // one day over
         showBanner();
     }
  } else {
    // first visit
    localStorage.setKey('timestamp', new Date().getTime());
    showBanner();
  }
};
```

And show your banner in `showBanner()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using localStorage and keeping 24 hours as the constrain

```
<script>
if (localStorage.firsttime==1)
{
var currenttime=new Date().getTime();
var firstvisittime=localStorage.visittime;
var difference=currenttime-firstvisittime;

var hoursDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60);
if( hoursDifference>24)
{
localStorage.firsttime=0;
} 

}

if(localStorage.firsttime==undefined||localStorage.firsttime==0)
{
localStorage.firsttime=1;
localStorage.visittime=new Date().getTime();
} 


</script>
```